VS Code how to attach terminal to spawned shell deployStep
In VS code, I need to launch an application that starts gdbserver on a remote device, and I need to run it while I am running cppdbg.  This works as shown in the snippet below.
BUT...
That command that is running gdbserver is also semihosting, with text output, so I need to watch it, also I want to see if there are any errors.
Right now, I am launching it as a deployStep's with type shell but - this seems to launch it in the background. How would I launch a task like this in the foreground?  I can't seem to find documentation showing how a shell step can be spawned in a new terminal window in VS code.
I have a launch.json that looks like the following:
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "GDB Debug Target",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "debugprintfdemo.elf",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "deploySteps": [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "continueOn": "GDBServer",
                "command": "make --directory=${workspaceFolder} closechlink flash gdbserver",
            },
        ],
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "miDebuggerPath": "gdb-multiarch",
        "miDebuggerServerAddress": "127.0.0.1:2000",
        "console" : "integratedConsole",
    },
    {
        "name": "Run Only (In Terminal)",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "",
        "preLaunchTask": "run_flash_and_gdbserver",
    }   
    ]
}


The solution was, instead of using deploySteps, to instead make a task and specify it as a preLaunchTask.
So, the final configuration would read:
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GDB Debug Target",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "debugprintfdemo.elf",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "run_flash_and_gdbserver",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb-multiarch",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "127.0.0.1:2000"
        },
...

And the new task, in tasks.json reads

        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "run_flash_and_gdbserver",
            "command": "make flash gdbserver",

            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "focus": false,
                "group": "build",
                "panel": "shared",
                "close": true,
                "showReuseMessage" : false
            },

            "isBackground": true,
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "instanceLimit": 2,
            },           
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "pattern": [
                    {
                        "regexp": ".",
                        "file": 1,
                        "location": 2,
                        "message": 3
                    }
                ],

                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": false,
                    "beginsPattern": "^.*Image written.*",
                    "endsPattern": "^.*GDBServer*"
                }
            },
        }

